# Proof of Diagonal lemma

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> **Lemma :(Diagonal lemma)**
>
> Let $\{x_n\}_{n\in I_m}$ be a sequence $\forall m = 1, 2, ...$. Such that $\{x_n\}_{n\in I_{m+1}}$ is a subsequence of $\{x_n\}_{n\in I_m}$.
>
> Then there exists a subsequence  $\{x_n\}_{n\in J}$ of $\{x_n\}_{n\in I_m}$ $\forall  m = 1, 2, ...$.

**Proof:**

> Let  $J = \{n_1, n_2, ...\}$ such that : $n_m$ is the smallest member of
> $$
> I_1 \cap I_2 \cap.... \cap I_m \cap \{m,m + 1, ...\}
> $$
> Since $n_k \in I_m$ for all $k\ge m$, it follows that $\{x_n\}_{n\in J}$  is a sub-sequence of $\{x_n\}_{n\in I_m}$  for all $m = 1, 2, ...$

I read this proof several times, but I did not understand why :  $\{x_n\}_{n\in J}$  is a sub-sequence of $\{x_n\}_{n\in I_m}$.

Is the definition of a sub-sequence: the existence of an infinity of sub-sequence indices which are in the global sequence or else the sequence contains the entire sub-sequence?

An idea please

Comment: I feel that I am missing something... what if $\bigcap_{m=1}^\infty I_m = \emptyset$? e.g. if $I_m = \{m, m+1, m+2, \ldots \}$

Comment: no this lemma exists but the problem in the proof

Comment: @Taylor $I_{m+1}\subset I_{m}$ then $\bigcap_{m=1}^\infty I_m\neq \emptyset$

Comment: @WerWer That's not true. Look at my example above.

Comment: No that since $I_{m} \subseteq I_{m-1} \subseteq I_{m-2} \cdots \subseteq I_1$ the $I_1 \cap I_2 \cap \cdots \cap I_m$ in the proof is just $I_m$.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am missing the gist of this, but all this seems to be is an (unnecessarily?) abstruse formulation of the diagonalization procedure. Since

$I_{m+1}\subseteq I_m,$ we have  $I_1 \cap I_2 \cap.... \cap I_m \cap \{m,m + 1, ...\}=I_m\cap \{m,m + 1, ...\}$.

So, the lemma provides the usual  recipe for choosing a subsequence which is $eventually$ a subsequence of each $\{x_n\}_{n\in I_m}:$

From the sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\in I_1}$, choose the least integer $n_1\in I_1$ and then the element of the sequence that corresponds to it, $x_{n_1}$. Now, from the sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\in I_2}$, choose, if this is possible, the least integer $n_2$ in $I_2$ that is greater than $n_1$ and then select the element $x_{n_2}\in \{x_n\}_{n\in I_2}$ that corresponds to it. If this is not possible, then the subsequence is the singleton $x_{n_1}$.

At the $k^{th}$ step, we have a sequence $\{n_j\}^k_{j=1}$ of integers, such that $n_{j+1}>n_j$ and such that the sequence $\{x_{n_1},\cdots, x_{n_k}\}$ satisfies: $\{x_{n_j}, x_{n_{j+1}},\cdots x_{n_k}\}$ is a subsequence of $\{x_n\}_{n\in I_j}$.

Now, from the sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\in I_{k+1}}$, if it is possible to choose the least integer $n_{k+1}\in I_{k+1}$, then do so and then select the element of the sequence that corresponds to it, $x_{n_{k+1}}$. If it is not possible to make this choice, then stop. This completes the induction step.

We now have either a finite sequence $\{x_{n_1},\cdots, x_{n_k}\}$ that satisfies: $\{x_{n_j}, x_{n_{j+1}},\cdots x_{n_k}\}$ is a subsequence of $\{x_n\}_{n\in I_j}$ or an infinite sequence with the same property.

Comment: Aha, "*eventually* a subsequence".  Thanks for making sense of this for me.

Comment: But what is the set $J$ in this demonstration?

Comment: @JairTaylor You are welcome, glad to help.

Comment: @johnatanjohn I don't understand your question. Could you elaborate?

Comment: "If this is not possible..." it should always be possible, yes?  I assume each $I_m$ is an infinite set of integers so will have arbitrarily high values

Comment: If you assume $I_m$ infinite yes. But there is no reason to do so.

Comment: @Metematleta, I did not understand your proof, the lemma says that we can build a set $J$ such that there exists a subsequence $\{x_n\}_{n\in J}$ of $\{x_n\}_{n\in I_m}$  $\forall m=1,2,....$. But this does not exist in your  response. In addition I want to thank you for your advance

Comment: @johnatanjohn The set $J$ is my set $\{n_j\}^k_{j=1}$ where $k$ may be $\infty$.